# KeyValuePair with DateTime as key not getting sorted

Tags: c#, sorting, datetime, collections

I have to parce a log file with data in following format:

Test Scenario Passed : Name: Scenario_48_12/19/2016 1:30:42 AM, Test result : True

I need data like this 1:30,True for one day::

```
var result = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>>();
var commaSeperatedTimeStamp = string.Empty;

  foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(logsPath, "ApplicationLogs*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            var perLineText = File.ReadAllText(file).Split('\n');
            foreach (var item in perLineText)
            {
                if (item.Contains("Scenario"))
                {
                    var timeStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(item.Split(',')[0].Split('/').Last().Substring(4).Trim(), "h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    result.Add(new KeyValuePair<DateTime, string>(timeStamp, 
                                                                item.ToLower().Contains("true") 
                                                                              ? "true" 
                                                                              : "false"));
                }
            }
        }

        result.OrderBy(x => x.Key.TimeOfDay);
        return result;
```

result variable is not sorted.

There are multiple issues with this code

1: Log files have the time in format hh:mm:ss but when I am converting it to DateTime it adds current date value into it. which I dont want.

2. I want the logs data sorted by time of day(better if I can disgard seconds also). But when I am using OrderBy values not getting sorted.

Please suggest.

Comment: Hi! If you work only with time format, you can use TimeStamp and TimeSpan.Parse(string) method to parse a string into TimeStamp. So, the KeyValuePair will we <TimeStamp, string> instead of <DateTime, string>. The date part will not be added when parsing in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used sort in place of OrderBy

```
result.Sort((a, b) => a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key));
```

Exact reason I am still trying to find out, will post that too.

Comment: did u find it ?

Answer (score 0):

2. Answer

OrderBy return type IOrderedEnumarable , So you need to translate it to the list

```
result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Key.TimeOfDay).ToList();
```

1. Answer

only time data in row text
Regex test link : http://rubular.com/r/0pYoiOCvto

```
 string text = "Name: Scenario_48_12/19/2016 1:30:42 AM, Test result : True";
        var m = new Regex(@"(\d+)[:.](\d+)[:.](\d+)").Match(text);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            TimeSpan d = TimeSpan.Parse(m.Value);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual in the code you try to take substring 4 so you will get 1:30:42 AM and so you  get current datetime is taken as default with the time we add.

Change your code to:

//This will give the actual datetime given in log and then do order by

```
  var actual = perLineText.Split(',')[0].Split('_').Last().ToString();

   var timeStamp = DateTime.ParseExact(actual, "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

//reassign result 
     result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Key.TimeOfDay);
      return result;
```

I did orderby and i got results orderd.

Also Note ,  your orderby on time will orderby time alone even if the dates are different.  You should orderby key itslef if u want the list to be ordered properly by date and time.

Comment: These logs are only from one day. so date will always be same.

Comment: ok. values where getting sorted . Can u post  ascreenshot of the results where we can see unsorted results ?

Comment: @Moody : you hav done order by but you hav not reassigned result object with the ordered result. you are returning result alone not the updated.